# I am trying to make delete btn but its not working

Tags: javascript, function, calculator

I am trying to make a delete button for my calculator project. But, its not working well.

```js
deleteBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){
    console.log(result.textContent.length);

    if (result.textContent !== "") {
        var text = result.textContent;
        var newText = String(text).slice(0, -1);
        result.textContent = parseFloat(newText);
    } 
    if (result.textContent.length == 1) {
        result.textContent = "";
    }
    
})
```

result is area where the numbers are

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) - please add relevant HTML and CSS

Comment: String(text) on textContent is a waste of time for one

Comment: If result area content is 123 it deletes 3 but if result length is 2 it deletes all numbers like, 123 delete = 12 , 12 delete = , but i want to delete just one like 12 delete = 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot parseFloat empty string

I suggest

```
result.textContent = +newText || "";
```

```js
const result = document.getElementById("result");
const deleteBtn = document.getElementById("deleteBtn");
deleteBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){
console.log(result.textContent.length);
if (result.textContent !== "") {
  var text = result.textContent;
  var newText = text.slice(0, -1);
  console.log(newText)
//  result.textContent = parseFloat(newText || "");
  result.textContent = +newText || "";
}
})
```

```html
<button id="deleteBtn">delete</button>
<div id="result">123</div>
```

Comment: Its cannot be empty while parsefloat is working

Comment: I updated - the if after update was not correct

Comment: PS: Don't apply for a job in Holland unless you change your name: `kut` is `amcık` in Dutch

Comment: Okay but its still not working. It deletes all, when there 2 numbers

Comment: No it doesn't Look at my updated script. I think perhaps you add the event handler twice? But I cannot tell because you did not post enough code